# How to store several results with different types (numeric & character)?

Tags: r

I know this kind of question have been asked before but I haven't been able to apply the proposed solutions to my dataset...
I have a really simple function to gather different data into a bigger dataframe (something about 7columns and 150 000 rows). My issue is to store the gathered data. Indeed, I have some strings character but also numerics and times.

```
 Location   Date Creneau Ordre              Name         Qte_conso    Start        End
case 2 18/12/2018       6     1         Caligula Time         0     06:28:35     06:28:35
case 2 18/12/2018       6     2         Lolita Forest       500     07:52:34     08:02:02
case 2 18/12/2018       6     3       Break The Wall       501     08:05:43     08:10:04
case 2 18/12/2018       6     4         Lolita Forest         0     08:10:55     08:11:35
case 2 18/12/2018       6     5          I Know you       501     08:12:43     08:24:26
case 2 18/12/2018       6     6         Caligula Time         0     08:24:39     08:24:39
case 2 18/12/2018       6     7             Aroma         421     08:34:37     08:40:56
case 2 18/12/2018       6     8             Polenta         0     08:41:44     08:41:45
case 2 18/12/2018       6     9             Aroma          79     08:41:49     08:45:43
case 2 18/12/2018       6    10            Polenta       500     08:46:54     08:58:23
case 2 18/12/2018       9     1           I Know you       501     09:03:09     09:11:17
case 2 18/12/2018       9     2             Polenta        500     09:12:03     09:25:34
case 2 18/12/2018       9     3             Decided       500     09:28:15     09:47:34
case 2 18/12/2018       9     4       Lolita Forest       500     09:48:05     09:56:49
case 2 18/12/2018       9     5          Diamond Free       500     09:57:07     10:07:23
time.interval
    0 secs
    568 secs
    261 secs
    40 secs
    703 secs
    0 secs
    379 secs
     1 secs
   234 secs
   689 secs
   488 secs
   811 secs
   1159 secs
   524 secs
   616 secs
```

Each row indicates at which time and how much an animal has eaten. Then, I have several rows for a unique animal.

I have the following code to gather the informations I need (this should be a more efficient way to do this but, at least it works, I've checked by printing the output on few individuals) :

```
 names <- unique(dataset$Nom)
 dates <- unique(dataset$Date)
 crnx <- unique(dataset$Creneau)

for (name in names){
 for (date in dates) {
   for (crn in crnx) {

   res <- subset(dataset, Nom==name & Date==date & Creneau==crn)
   nbPassage <- nrow(res) 
   qteMax <- max(res$Qte_conso)
   qteMin <- min(res$Qte_conso)
   qteTot <- sum(res$Qte_conso)
   qteMoy <- mean(res$Qte_conso)

   tempsMin <- min(res$interval)
   tempsMax <- max(res$interval)
   tempsTot <- sum(res$interval)
   tempsMoy <- mean(res$interval)
   }
 }
}
```

I have tried to put all those into a blank dataframe initialized as follow :

```
df <- data.frame(Nom=character(),
             Date=character(),
             Case=character(),
             Creneau=numeric(),
             Passage=numeric() ,
             Qte_min=numeric(),
             Qte_max=numeric(),
             Qte_tot=numeric(),
             Qte_moy=numeric(),
             Tps_min=character(),
             Tps_max=character(),
             Tps_tot=character(),
             Tps_moy=character(),
             stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

for (name in names){
  for (date in dates) {
    for (crn in crnx) {

    res <- subset(dataset, Nom==name & Date==date & Creneau==crn)
    [...]

    }
  }
df$Nom <- df$Nom + name
   df$Date <- df$Date + date
   df$Creneau <- df$Creneau + crn
   df$Passage <- df$Passage + nbPassage

   df$Qte_min <- df$Qte_min + qteMin
   df$Qte_max <- df$Qte_max + qteMax
   df$Qte_tot <- df$Qte_tot + qteTot
   df$Qte_moy <- df$Qte_moy + qteMoy

   df$Tps_min <- df$Tps_min + tempsMin
   df$Tps_max <- df$Tps_max + tempsMax
   df$Tps_tot <- df$Tps_tot + tempsTot
   df$Tps_moy <- df$Tps_moy + tempsMoy
}
```

With this one I end up with `Error in df$Nom + name : non-numeric argument to binary operator`

I've also tried with vectors (I've red it's not a good practice to do so but as I don't really know how to proceed), knowing how many rows I should obtain but then I had `integer(0)` for all the numeric once and the exact same error message for one containing strings of characters.

I've also tried `capture.output` but I only got the first element.

The final goal of all this is to be able to export the new dataframe into a csv file.

Thank you in advance to those who will take the time to read and maybe answer this. If you need any extra information I would be glad to give you more elements.

Comment: Please post a short sample of your data e.g. `dput(dataset[1:20,])` #minimalreproducibleexample:)

Comment: I've had totaly forgot about it ! I've added an exemple for 15 lines of the dataset.

Comment: For a reproducible example, it is better than you use the command `dput` on your dataframe and then paste the output of this function here.
You can have more informations on the following thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: For an unknown reason `dput` only gave me hours when I tried it earlier. I'll have a look to the link you gave me and try make it clearer. Thanks again (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that what you want to do is just a **group by** operation. You can use the package `data.table` (as well as `dplyr`) to do this operation.

Let's say I have a `data.frame` of animals of names `animal_names` who eat a certain amout of food `quantity` at each time period (I omit the time variable for conciseness):

```
animal_names <- c(rep("Pierre", 2), rep("Jean", 4))
quantity     <- runif(n = 6, min = 1, max = 10)
df           <- data.frame(names = animal_names, quantity = quantity)
```

which yields:

```
 > df
   names quantity
1 Pierre 7.620816
2 Pierre 2.754536
3   Jean 2.591135
4   Jean 4.013869
5   Jean 3.865716
6   Jean 7.888450
```

Instead of looping on `unique(names)` and computing aggregate measures such as `max(quantity)`, `mean(quantity)`, etc., you can do a group by operation. Using the package `data.table`, you can do the following:

```
dt <- data.table(df) #to convert the data.frame object into a data.table
summary_df <- dt[, .(
  min_qty = min(quantity),
  max_qty = max(quantity),
  mean_qty = mean(quantity),
  sum_qty = sum(quantity)
), by = names]
```

which yields:

```
> summary_df
    names  min_qty  max_qty mean_qty  sum_qty
1: Pierre 2.754536 7.620816 5.187676 10.37535
2:   Jean 2.591135 7.888450 4.589792 18.35917
```

Then export this data.table the function `write.csv`. If you want to work on this table but does not know data.table syntax you can always cast your object into a back into a `data.frame` using the command: `summary_df <- data.frame(summary_dt)`.

Comment: I'll try this ! I hope I'll be able to apply it correctly.

Comment: Worked perfectly (: After a bit of research I was able to use it with my severals conditions. You've definitely saved my day ! Thank you very much

Comment: You are welcome !
Also, you might already know, the group by can be done on multiple variable. For instance if you have another date column (`date_eating`)and you want to group by name AND month you would set the by argument of data.table as: 
`by = .(names, month(date_eating))`

Answer (score 0):

There are many dplyr options to do this but with base R, you can use  `by` for example:

```
by(dataset[, c("Qte_conso", "interval")], dataset[c("name", "date", "crn")], function(x) with(x, data.frame(qteMax=max(Qte_conso), qteMin=min( ....
```

A working example with contrived data:

```
df <- data.frame(g1=sample(1:3, 100, replace=T), g2=sample(1:2, 100, replace=T), b=rnorm(100), c=rnorm(100))
foo <- by(df[, c("b", "c")], df[c("g1", "g2")], function(x) 
  c(len = nrow(x), minb=min(x$b), maxb=max(x$b), minc=min(x$c), maxc=max(x$c)))
do.call(rbind, foo)
cbind( expand.grid(attr(foo, "dimnames")), do.call(rbind, foo))
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't really get it... I suppose it seems quite easy to you but I'm a beginner with R and if I get the first line with the dataframe creation, then I'm lost. I understand that, at some point, you simply bind the different vector you have created but I don't get the intermediate steps